# Read a file and return a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have this function that  return a pointer to an allocated book inside this function, and the data comes from a file called book_saved.dat. I can compile this code but it sends me garbage, why?

book_saved is a file that already exists

*I have the struct in my original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


book_t *book_load(){

    book_t *book;// book_t is a struct

    book = (book_t*)malloc(sizeof(book_t));

    if (book == NULL)
        exit(1);

    FILE*fp = fopen ("book_saved.dat", "rb");

    fread (book, sizeof(book_t), 1, fp);

    return book;

}

void print_book (book_t *book) {

    printf("\n");
    printf ("Book \nTitle: %s\nWriter: %s\nPublishing: %s\nYear: %d\nWeight %.1f\n", book->title, book->writer, book->publishing_house, book->year, book->weight);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    book_t *pontaux = book_load();
    print_book (pontaux);

    free (pontaux);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does the `book_saved.dat` file come from? Did you produce it using another program, or has it been entered manually with a text editor?

Comment: I did a program that write instead of read.

Comment: Are the members of book_t char pointers or arrays?

Comment: Arrays.

typedef struct book_t {
 char title[75];
 char writer [50];
 char publishing[30];
 int year;
 float weight; // kg.
} book_t;

Comment: @Kay It would help if you put the `typedef` for `book_t` into the question instead of just a comment.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will put next time. But I solved the problem, actually the problem was in the code that write the book_saved.dat. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide your writing function? I made a fairly basic one and it seems to work properly. I'd recommend sticking the `struct` in a shared header file just to make sure the structs used are absolutely the same, and also opening `book_saved.dat` in a hex editor to make sure the formatting in there's correct.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct book_t {
    char title[75];
    char writer [50];
    char publishing[30];
    int year;
    float weight; // kg. 
} book_t; 

void book_make(){

    book_t *book;// book_t is a struct

    book = (book_t*)malloc(sizeof(book_t));

    if (book == NULL)
        exit(1);
    strcpy(book->title, "Harry Potter: World\'s End");
    strcpy(book->writer, "JK Rowlingbatman");
    strcpy(book->publishing, "Publisherguy inc.");
    book->year = 3000;
    book->weight = 14.6;

    FILE*fp = fopen ("book_saved.dat", "wb");

    fwrite(book, sizeof(book_t), 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}


book_t *book_load(){

    book_t *book;// book_t is a struct

    book = (book_t*)malloc(sizeof(book_t));

    if (book == NULL)
        exit(1);

    FILE*fp = fopen ("book_saved.dat", "rb");

    fread (book, sizeof(book_t), 1, fp);

    return book;

}

void print_book (book_t *book) { 

    printf("\n");
    printf ("Book \nTitle: %s\nWriter: %s\nPublishing: %s\nYear: %d\nWeight %.1f\n", book->title, book->writer, book->publishing, book->year, book->weight);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    book_make();
    book_t *pontaux = book_load();
    print_book (pontaux);

    free (pontaux);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My writing function was wrong, I put a '&' in fwrite x)

Comment: No problem! It happens to the best of us. I can't give much advice other than code more or switch up to a language with better type safety